# What scriptures describe Shani as having six eyes?

Tags: temple, shani

I just came back from a trip to India, and one of the places I visited was my dad's native village of Kuchanoor. It's the site of the famous Kuchanoor Shanishwaran temple, one of the few temples in the world for Shani, god of the planet Saturn. For those who don't know, Shani is the son of Surya, the Sun god and his second wife Chaya, whom I discuss in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/545/36). Shani is in charge of dispensing good and bad fortune, and so people often come to Kuchanoor if they've been adversely affected by the gaze of Shani.

But my question is about the Shani idol in the Kuchanoor temple. It's a Swayambhu or divinely created statue, but it's not an anthropomorphic statue, rather it's a vague slab akin to a Shivalinga, on which various ornaments have been attached.  [Here](http://www.kuchanursaneeswarar.tnhrce.in/image/temple.jpg) is a picture of it:

[image]

My question is, why is Shani depicted as having six eyes?

Dasharatha's hymn to Shani in [this excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRZ2j.jpg) from the Padma Purana doesn't mention the number of eyes, it just calls him Vishalanetra or having big eyes.  But are there other scriptures which say that he has six eyes? Dhyana Shlokas, which I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7874/36), would be a good place to look for the details of Shani's appearance?

Also, if he does have six eyes, what is the reason for that? Shani is infamous for the ruinous power of his glance, as I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3044/36), so does he have so many eyes to in order to gaze at people?

Comment: Who is the female deity alongside shani deva idol? also notice the name adhodrishti which means he looks down everytime. In general shani deva idols are not made specifically looking at worshipper and if so then worshippers are told not to directly look into his eyes. Since shani deva's eye sight kills due to a curse from his own wife.

Comment: @Yogi I haven't heard the story of his wife cursing him, but I assume the female deity is his wife.  This answer mentions him having two wives: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/586/36

Comment: @Keshav The story of his wife cursing him is from the Brahmavaivarta Purana, where she curses him for giving more importance to the worship of Krsna than paying her attention (!!).

Comment: @Surya That's interesting, what chapter is that from?  Shanishwaran in Kuchanoor certainly has a Namam, but it may just be run by Vaishnavas.

Comment: It's from just before Ganesha's beheading: Shani narrates the story to Parvati

Comment: See shanidev had only two eyes but at different times the work was different.For ex-when he was cursed he had those two destroying eyes or ku-drishti at that time wherever he gazed was blasted off.....
2)well in the second case he was cured by the VARDAAN given to him by Shiva....
3)the third case implies that SHANI has both the drishti's in him to give the karmafal to everyone.....I think that's why there are six eyes mentioned.....If you all want to know everything about devtaas and danavaas.....Then stay tuned and ask