# What is the story of Lord Shani's wife Neelam?

Tags: astrology, brahma, curse, navagraha, shani

As discussed in this [QnA](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/560/what-is-the-story-behind-sons-of-shani?r=SearchResults), the Tamil version  attributes *Mandha Devi* & *Jyesta Devi* as Shani dev's wife. However, the more commonly accepted or albeit, say, as per the popular stories, it is the *gandharva Chitraratha's* daughter called *[Dhāminī or Māndā](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manda_(goddess))*, is mostly referred to as Shani's wife.

In several popular stories:

> She is said to be the one to have caused the *Vakrī dṛṣṭi (वक्री दृष्टि )* of *Shani* owing to his too much devotion towards either his tutelary deity, *Shri Krishna* or his *guru* Lord *Shiva* or either because of too much pre-occupation with his position of the *"Karma-adjuciator (कर्म फल दाता )"* of the mankind. Due to either of the cases, the final result being him neglecting his wife and thus the resultant curse of *vakri-drishti*. Thus, whomsoever he shall look onto or into, that person will suffer in some form or another. A popular [recession](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/27794/17833) of which is found in several alternate stories of the Lord *Ganesha* beheading episode where it's due to *Shani* looking at the newly manifested *Vināyaka*, which leads to his head being decapitated, in contrast to the rather the more popular recension of beheading by *Shiva* himself.

Anyway, my interest more lies with the occasionally alluded First wife (and in some cases kind of twin sibling too **?**) of Lord *Shani*, [***Nīlama or Nīlā or Nīlimā***](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neela_(goddess))

The Wikipedia page goes on as:

> In Hinduism, Neela is known as Neelima or Neelamratna. She is the first consort of Shani and mother of Kuligna. She balances and increases power of Shani and is the goddess of the gemstone sapphire. **She has the power of fifth head of Brahma**. Her son Kuligna is a Rishi. Her husband, Shani, also married a Gandharva lady, Dhamini.

The page further quotes the plot of a popular TV series based on *Shani Deva* and quotes as:

> According to the series, Neela and Shani both created by Shiva at the same time. But, Shani was Sakaratmaka Shakti (Positive energy) and Neela was Nakaratmaka Shakti (Negative energy). After birth of both, Neela was imprisoned by Lord Vishvakarman in his loka when she was in form of energy but after 12 years of her birth she came in body form.

---

So,

- Which scriptures talk about the *vakri-drishti* curse by his wife, *Dhāminī* on *Shani* ?
- What are the scriptural sources for Nīlimā, as either Lord *Shani's* wife or as per that TV show, the 'negatively created twin energy formed along with *Shani*, by Lord *Shiva* '?

It would also make sense for *Nīlimā*, to be as his wife considering we have a Nīlamaratna, i.e., the Blue Sapphire stone which is intricately connected with *Shani* and its remedial measures as per *Jyotisha* treatises.

- What's the validity and the implication of that Wikipedia's statement - *"She has the  power of the fifth head of *Brahmā (ब्रह्मा)"** ? As I recall, the fifth head was chopped off by *Shiva* at the beginning of creation itself. So, did somehow the head reconnected as a manifestations of *Nīlimā*? Any story in the scriptures on the same ?

Comment: Now I am wondering whether the Wikipedia page was created based on the TV Series Shani, and not any scriptures...

Comment: @Surya, IKR! I think many articles on wiki might be written as per TV shows scripts :P

Comment: lol, what triggered me was Manda's mother's name, Divyanka. That is a name which you might never encounter in any scripture, it's totally a modern Hindi name.

Comment: @Surya, see [this](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=SAoBEAAAQBAJ&pg=PT195&dq=%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%BE+%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%82&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZ5bTo1bnvAhWtlEsFHQttA8AQ6AEwAHoECAEQAw#v=onepage&q=%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%BE%20%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%82&f=false). I don't know what to make of it? Nonsense or logical, but it's interesting! :P :D

Comment: Can't view the page...

Comment: @Surya, try in in the actual browser maybe

Comment: oh God that looks atrocious