# What's the story of Shri Krishna becoming Cuckoo bird to meet Lord Shani?

Tags: krishna, temple, shani

There's a temple in Uttar Pradesh named [**Shri Shani Mandir Kokilavan**](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=kPJsDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA16&dq=krishna%20shani%20koyal&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiDzYG70LnvAhVWqksFHY18CvwQ6AEwAHoECAMQAw#v=onepage&q=krishna%20shani%20koyal&f=false).

The [popular story](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=5wITEAAAQBAJ&pg=PT105&dq=krishna%20shani%20Cuckoo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi16Z-40rnvAhUGOSsKHZgMC_YQ6AEwAHoECAAQAw#v=onepage&q=krishna%20shani%20Cuckoo&f=false) behind it being:

> During the stay of *Shri Krishna* in the *Gokula*, *Shani Deva* was desperate to meet his ishta or tutelary *Shri Krishna* in his *bālarūpama (बाल रूप )* or his Child form. But, since *Shani deva* possessed a "*Vakrī dṛṣṭi*" i.e., a destructive vision energy, the minor conjectured details of which I discuss in [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/45234/17833), thus Shri *Krishna* wasn't willing to meet *Shani deva* in his usual humanized form. Thus Krishna assumed the form of a *Kokila* or *Koyala* (कोकिल/कोयल)i.e., a Cuckoo bird, and requested *Shani* to not even come inside the Village (as that might be inauspicious for the whole village, since Shani being of malefic nature). Lord *Krishna* assuming the Cuckoo bird form flied out of the village and met *Shani deva* outside the village periphery.

The place where this meeting happened is posited as the present day setting for the above mentioned, Shri Shani Mandir Kokilavan temple.

So, what's the authentic scriptural sources for this story?
Also, why Shri *Krishna* be hesitant to meet *Shani-deva*, in his original form? Considering he's a God (even though if in a human form) himself? Was it one of his human *"leela"* or pastimes?